# Can I name the Omniauth authentication routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, omniauth

I've added Omniauth to my rails 3.1 project and it all works fine. When I visit `hostname/auth/facebook` I'm brought to a page where I can authorize access to my Facebook account as you would expect.

I'm wondering if I can name that route though so that in my `link_to` helpers I can write

```
<%= link_to 'Login with Facebook', facebook_login_path %>
```

instead of

```
<%= link_to 'Login with Facebook', '/auth/facebook' %>
```

Not a huge thing I know but I like the consistency.

Comment: Have you tried?: `match '/auth/facebook'` => '/auth/facebook', :as => facebook_login

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it fails with an error because it thinks that I'm matching to the "/auth" controller and controllers can't start with a slash. Without the slash it fails because there is no auth controller!

Comment: Yes, that is beacause `route.rb` file need to be used internally by Rails (it is just converts incoming http requests to REST style (and there should be controllers and actions to handle that)). In OAuth/OpenID case - you send request to external service - so anything you can do is to create helper method say in `application_helper` file (def facebook_login_path "/auth/facebook"; end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would do something like this: In your routes.rb file:

```
get "auth/facebook", :to => "controller#action", :as => "facebook_login"
```

But in this case, the url that you are sent to isn't actually a URL part of your application - but the oauth url for Facebook. Therefore, you can't create a route for it.

The only thing you could do - like the commenter above pointed out - is to create a helper method in one of your helper files - like app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def facebook_login_path
  "/auth/facebook"
end
```